# Android: right margin at Up button on the Toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, back-button

I'm setting custom view into my Toolbar:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
View customView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(resId, null);
actionBar.setCustomView(customView);
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```

It looks fine until I enabling Up button:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Here are pictures of the toolbar with Up button and without. I've added gray color to my custom view's background to view the real element size.

**Without:**
[image: without]

**With:**
[image: with]

And here is an image of Layout inspector window. There is a space between Up button and custom view.

[image: layout inspector]

Comment: post your `xml` and use `click listner` instead of `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this you have to write your own Up button:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/action_back"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_white"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
```

`android:onClick="onClick"` on your `Button` and сreate method in Java class like below way

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
     NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(TheoryActivity.this);
}
```

Comment: @ArtemMostyaev glad to know that.

Comment: Please look at my edit suggestion. It will be more clear and help someone in the future.